# Idiom for knowing every detail regarding a subject

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Related question: [Idiom for a person who knows every detail about something](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/277332/140931) (which is also [coincidentally](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7193/140931) asked by me!)

I'm asking for an idiom describing the **details** themselves, not the *person* who knows them. Some of the answers in the above link would be valid here, like *jot and tittle*.

My own guess would be something like this:

> Since he developed this software framework himself, he knows the _____ (and) _____ of it.

Comment: I guess know-it-all refers to the _person_, but as I stated in my question, I want an idiom describing the _details_. It could be posted in the link I provided in the beginning of my post (which asks for an idiom describing the person), however, I think _know-it-all_ has a negative sense to it and doesn't apply to that question either.

Comment: _Since he developed this software framework himself, he knows all the ins and outs of it._

Comment: @JoeDark you should post that suggestion, it's the one that popped into my head first.

Comment: The answers on this post are very similar to the ones you have provided the link to. I was expecting to see terms that described the person him/herself, not  the depth of their knowledge.

Comment: @JoeDark Please post your comment as an answer, so far that is the best answer I've seen and it's the candidate to be accepted.

Comment: The "alpha and omega of it".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Since he developed this software framework himself, he knows the ____ and ____ of it.*

*Since he developed this software framework himself, he knows the* ***ins*** *and* ***outs*** *of it.*

---

[*Ins and outs*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ins%20and%20outs):

1. characteristic peculiarities or technicalities :  workings
2. ramifications

Comment: If you provide links to definition of this, I would accept this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Done (picked the first google hit).

Answer (score 5):

- knows it **inside and out**

[To know something "inside out" or "inside and out"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165355/to-know-something-inside-out-or-inside-and-out)

- knows it **from A to Z**

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/from-a-to-z

- knows it **backwards and forwards**

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/know+backwards+and+forwards

Answer (score 1):

He knows it **from the ground up**.

from the ground up: from the most basic level to the highest level; completely ([American Heritage Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/from+the+ground+up))

Answer (score 0):

You could say that he knows all the ***[specifics](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/specifics):***

> - exact details. (Cambridge Dictionary)
> - distinct items or details; particulars (AHD)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for an idiom. Can you think of an idiom I can use?